# CommandGroup with keyboardShortcut (Command + O)

Tags: macos, swiftui, menuitem

As I understand, I need to use `CommandGroup` in the `App` struct to set up menu items in SwiftUI.  So I have the following.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct Oh_My_App: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView(menuObservable: menuObservable)
        }.commands {
            CommandGroup(replacing: .newItem) {
                
            }
            CommandGroup(after: .newItem) {
                Button {
                    
                } label: {
                    Text("Open...")
                }
                .keyboardShortcut("O")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I launch the application, I find my Open command as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

Well, my key equivalent is **O**.  So the shortcut is supposed to be Command + O.  But my Open command gets Command + Shift + O, which suggets that the O keyequivalent has been taken by something else.  But by what!?  There are only a dozen reserved commands as shown in the following screenshot.  None of them uses O.

[image]

So my question is how can I assign Command + O to my Open command?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a lowercase `"o"`, it will remove the Shift (which is a modifier that makes the `"O"` uppercase):

```
.keyboardShortcut("o")
```

Comment: Oh, I see.  Thanks.  I'll accept it in 4 minutes.